# Jenkins Pipeline - Remote Build

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to the Jenkins, please help me. I want to build the job on a remote server by default. But is is trying to build on master.

I have below pipeline script. 
--Test_Pipeline---

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test1') {
            steps {
                build job: 'Job1', 
                     parameters: [
                                    string(name: 'Environment', value: 'dev'),
                                    string(name: 'ProjectName', value: 'Temp'),
                                    string(name: 'JobName', value: 'Job1'),
                                    string(name: 'Parameters', value: 'Dummy')
                                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--
When I don't pass the "parameters" it is building the job remotely. But with the parameters, it builds on master.

With parameter:

Started by upstream project "Test_Pipeline" build number 21

```
originally caused by:
 Started by user Temp1
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace E:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Job1\workspace
No emails were triggered.
[workspace] $ sh -xe C:\Users\ZPAPPB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson7083850686294271347.sh
+ /opt/ibm/scripts/bin/Exec.ksh run Temp Job1 Dummy
-----
```

Without Parameter:

Started by upstream project "Test_Pipeline" build number 22

```
originally caused by:
 Started by user Temp1
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on appserver01 in workspace /opt/jenkins/workspace/JobExecution
No emails were triggered.
[JobExecution] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2555136363794702914.sh
+ /opt/ibm/scripts/bin/Exec.ksh run def1 Job2 Dummy
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is built remotely because parameters. The `agent any`  is what allow Jenkins to build the job in, you know, any agent.

Setting it to `agent { label 'appserver01' }` will restrict the builds to that node.

See [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) for other options.